# Searching for reference regarding the impact of famine on a woman's grandchildren

Tags: human-genetics, nutrition, epigenetics

I was once told that if a woman experiences a famine, her grandchildren will show epigenetic changes because the egg that the intervening mother came from also experienced the famine.

In other words, the grandchild would be more susceptible to obesity, due to the grandmother's nutritional environment, even though the famine might have been 40-50 years distant.

However, I can't remember where I heard this, and could not locate a reference.

Comment: Welcome to Biology StackExchange. Take a look at [Transgenerational epigenetic inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transgenerational_epigenetic_inheritance). Plenty of explanations and references.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article in Science about the phenomenon:

https://www.science.org/content/article/moms-environment-during-pregnancy-can-affect-her-grandchildren

It references a variety of different studies, not sure which you are most familiar with, but they include a population study of Dutch children whose grandmothers were pregnant with their mothers in 1944 and some more mechanistic studies in mice.